# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Я уже не понимаю в чем еще может быть проблема, в логах проверил нет ошибок nginx и puma запущены. В браузере выдает по имени сервера такую ошибку  **(113) No route to host**, а если зайти по ip то вот такую **502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)**.

## ps aux | grep nginx

```
root     23336  0.0  0.0  58808  1068 ?        Ss   13:56   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx    23337  0.0  0.0  59672  2320 ?        S    13:56   0:00 nginx: worker process
root     23416  0.0  0.0 112680   976 pts/3    R+   14:19   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

## ps aux | grep puma

```
root     22994  0.0  1.1 811892 44616 pts/1    Sl+  13:47   0:01 puma 3.11.0 (unix:///tmp/puma.sock) [phonebookapi]
root     23418  0.0  0.0 112680   972 pts/3    R+   14:20   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

В чем еще может быть проблема подскажите пожалуйста (только поподробнее если можно)? 
Если нужно еще что-то скинуть, например деплой или что-то в этом роде напишите.

**config/nginx.conf:**

```
upstream puma {
  server              unix:///tmp/puma.sock;
}

server {
        listen   80 default_server;
        listen   [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name         10.12.4.245;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location /favicon.ico {
    root              /var/www/phonebookapi/phonebook-app/dist/assets/images/favicon.ico;
    gzip_static       on;
    expires           max;
    add_header        Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    root              /var/www/phonebookapi/phonebook-app/dist;
    try_files         $uri @app;
    index             index.html index.htm;
    gzip_static       on;
    expires           max;
    add_header        Cache-Control public;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_pass        http://puma;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502;
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите `ls -l /tmp/puma.sock`

Comment: А также причина проблемы может быть написана в `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: У вас лишние слеши. Попробуйте так `server              unix:/tmp/puma.sock;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen вроде как лишние слеши работе не мешают

Comment: @andreymal # ls -l /tmp/puma.sock srwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 дек 18 13:47 /tmp/puma.sock

Comment: На 502 точно должны быть какие-то записи в логе nginx

Comment: `No route to host` — проверьте DNS

Comment: исчерпался лимит на плюсики к комменатриям, так что словами напишу, что если у вас No route to host, то у вас можно даже не смотреть, что на сервере работает -- тупо не доходит запрос до сервера.